# Regex to match letters, spaces, and ampersand only

Tags: regex, ampersand

I'm trying to use regex to match strings with letters, spaces, and ampersands, e.g. "Johnson & Johnson Company"

I've tried `^[a-zA-Z\s&]*$` which did not work. the regex `^[a-zA-Z\s]*$` let me match letters and spaces properly, but now I'm trying to include ampersands. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is it used in some XML? Does `&amp;`  instead of `&` work? Are you running the regex against plain text or entitized string? As a test, try `^[a-zA-Z\s;&]*$` to match the string you have. If it matches, you are not using plain text.

Comment: In what context is the regex being used?

Comment: I've tried &amp; and it didn't work unfortunately. I'm using it as part of a data analysis process, trying to filter the rows in a dataset. Currently experimenting here https://regex101.com/r/sFsNRn/1

Comment: Could you elaborate how you came to the conclusion that `^[a-zA-Z\s&]*$` would not work?

Answer (score 0):

Update, this is how you do it

`'^[a-zA-Z\s\&]*$'`

Comment: Why? `&` is never special in a regex pattern.